# check the no. of mail in mail queue is pending

Tags: bash, scripting

I know the linux command "mailq" can be used to check any mail is pending , if I would like to get the alert if the no. of pending mail is over 500 , would advise what can I do , if a script can do that ? very thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is just a brief outline of the concept.

```
count=`mailq | grep "Total requests" | awk -F: {'print $2'}`; if [ $count -ge 500 ]; then echo "CRITICAL: Mailq exceeded $count" ; fi
```

The alert configuration depends on how you are trying to configure the same. For example : use monitoring tools like nagios.

Comment: I used double brackets `count=`mailq | grep "Total requests" | awk -F: {'print $2'}`; if [[ $count -ge 500 ]]; then echo "CRITICAL: Mailq exceeded $count" ; fi`